# SeleniumWebdriver: Implement Page Object Pattern in Python using Pycharm tool

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pycharm, browser-automation

Dear Test Automation Engineers,
I am implementing **Page Object Pattern** in **Python Language** using **Pycharm tool**.
My concerns are followings:

1. **Structure of Project - 2 tier:**
   Under project folder: I want 2 packages(folder in python, pycharm): 1 folder should contain all tests to execute while other package should contain element locators blah blah etc [I would appreciate if you please share screenshot of structure heir-achy of project]
2. I am facing problem in calling element locators from other package(folder)
3. Locators should be page wise not complete locators of project in one file(it creates mess! - share best approaches)

**IMP:** I don't want locators files(.py) and Testcases in one folder, should be in separate folders.

I have gone through few examples on web but they are not 2-tier and don't follow Page object model structure project exactly.

Comment: Here is my [structure](http://screencast.com/t/04qZlxYhdl6) (for Java, but core ideas are the same). To projects b2b and b2c, each contain test package and ui.pages package, common - shared classes (e.g. for manage Wedriver) and utils. Framewor packages contains data providers.

Comment: Thanks @EnotEnotovich can you please share basic running demo source code because I am facing problems in code while calling/importing locators from locator class when class is located in other package(not same)

Comment: Is it your goal to have the second package (with the locators) be re-usable across Python projects?

Comment: I don't know python syntax, but suppose it should be something the same as import in java. You may try https://github.com/actmd/elementium

Comment: Yes @PaulEveritt because this makes it exact Page Object Model and not by having locators in same package. Suppose I have 20 test cases and 100+ pages in my web app, so it means there will be 20 classes for each test case(obvious) and 100+ classes(.py file) for each page to contain locators of that page. So, same package will contain more than 120+ files so it will make mess! I think putting locators in different package will make some sense of keeping tests in separate package and locators in separate.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you'd like to use that package of locators and helpers on your current web app project and on future web app projects, right?

If so, then it's a case of Python Packaging. Not the simplest topic, but well-documented and very standard (nothing unique to PyCharm.)

If not, and you just want your current project to be able to import that folder, then you need to get that directory on your PYTHONPATH. In your PyCharm Run Configuration, add that path to the run configuration's PYTHONPATH.